# Should I use loves or love

Tags: grammatical-number

This is a quote that I got from one of our customers:
"I'm proud to be part of an elite group of individuals that genuinely **loves** going to work on a Monday morning!"

Comment: This depends on whether you are treating the group as a composite unit, or as a number of individuals.

Comment: Although I'd choose 'who' with 'love'.